# Why is there a difference between console formatting of an array, and that array copied with the spread operartor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm executing a very simple snippet of Javascript code in Chrome 104.0.5112.101 (Official 64 bit Build) on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (with Gnome):

```
let arrTest = [1,2,3,4]
let arr = arrTest
console.log(arr)
```

gives the output in console as `▾ Array(4)`:

[image: Output 1]

but, executing what is basically the same code but with the spread operator gives *different* console output, showing `▾ (4) [1, 2, 3, 4]` instead:

```
let arrTest = [1,2,3,4]
let arr = [...arrTest]
console.log(arr)
```

[image]

Can someone please explain why two different console logs for what are basically the same arrays generates different output?

Comment: What are you asking about. The fact that the console shows `▾ Array(4)` for the first, but `▾ (4) [1, 2, 3, 4]` in the second instance?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
 Yes why is the output in a different style when both of them are arrays?

Comment: depends entirely on your browser really. In Firefox I get `▾ Array(4) [1, 2, 3, 4 ]` for both your cases, as well as the direct `console.log([...[1,2,3,4]]);` whereas in Chrome I get `▾ (4) [1, 2, 3, 4]` in all those cases. How `console.log` logs is [left up to whoever implements it](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the info, so there is really no differnece between them apart from one holding a refernece and other one being a copy.

Comment: Correct. But if you still want an answer on why _a single browser_ has two different console log outputs for what is the same data, you'll need to update your post to include which browser, and which version of that browser, on which platform, and which version of that platform, you're seeing this happen in.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you please make this a comment so i can mark this as answered?

Comment: there's nothing to answer: what you're showing in your post is not what I see when I run your code in either Chrome or Firefox, so my comment doesn't actually explain the thing you're asking about. It just comments on the fact that console log behaviour is not regulated by the spec and explains why I'm _not_ seeing the same thing.